# Check if an expression can be used (QGIS version)

Tags: qgis

I have different people using predifined layout. Some of them are on QGIS 3.16 and some on 3.22.

In the layout, I want to use something like that:

```
CASE
WHEN  @qgis_short_version <3.22 THEN 'Fond de carte: © Swisstopo'
WHEN map_credits('carte1') IS NULL Then ''
ELSE 'source: © '||array_to_string( array_sort( map_credits('carte1')), ', ')
END
```

The problem is that on 3.16, it can't evaluate the expression cause `map_credits()`doesn't exist.

Is it a way to do that? Meaning if I'm on 3.16, it evaluate only the first "WHEN", and not the next one?

Comment: You could use try() expression.

Comment: I don't understand how to use this expression... it only return true/false (1/0).

Comment: From help for function try: "Tries an expression and returns its value if error-free. If the expression returns an error, an alternative value will be returned when provided otherwise the function will return NULL." Syntax: `try(expression[,alternative])`, see: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#try

Comment: With try(), it doesn’t work, cause in 3.16, it says invalid expression, and not « error ».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea to solve the problem contains of three basic ideas:

1. Create the `map_credits()` part as a string: as long as you create it as a function, QGIS 3.16 will not recognize the function and prompt an error.
2. Then use the function `eval()` ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#eval)) to convert the string to a function.
3. The `eval()`-function should be called only for QGIS versions larger than 3.x (I don't know exactly when `map_credits()` was introduced). Use an additional `if`-condition for that. So the string containing `map_credits()` will only be evaluated (converted from string to actual function) for QGIS versions > 3.x.

The expression will look something like this (see the `map_credits()` part on line 11) - this exact expression works in my QGIS 3.16 installation.

*Be aware: inside the `eval()` function, everythis is a string, enclosed in single quotes `'`. Single quotes that appear inside this string must be masked by two additional single quotes - thus `'''` (3 single quotes) evaluates as `'` (1 single quote), `''''` (4 single quotes) as `''` (2 single quotes = empty string).*

```
if (
    @qgis_short_version < 3.18,
    CASE
        WHEN  @qgis_short_version <3.22  -- change the QGIS version here
        THEN 'Fond de carte: © Swisstopo'
    END,
    eval('
        CASE
        WHEN  @qgis_short_version <3.22 
        THEN ''Fond de carte: © Swisstopo'' 
        WHEN map_credits(''carte1'') IS NULL 
        THEN ''''
        ELSE ''source: © ''||array_to_string( array_sort( map_credits(''carte1'')), '', '')
        END
    ')
)
```